# Get list of unused LAN IP addresses

Tags: java, lan

How could I get the list of not used IP addresses in LAN with Java? I really need it. If it worked just on Windows, it would be enough.

I tried to connect `Socket` to every IP address in range of 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.255, but I had to specify port, and I think there always doesn't have to be some server on the called address.

And the method `isReachable()` of `InetAddress` class is not working for me.

I could also use some command in Command Prompt using `exec()`, but I don't know any command doing this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "not used." Is it sufficient to say that if you can't ping the address, it's not being used?

Comment: What do you mean by _not used_? Unless you're the router, there's no way to tell for sure.

Comment: Well when the target doesn't respond to ping, it doesn't mean it is unused. But there has to be some way how to get the list of used/unused IP addresses in LAN (maybe from cmd), because when I open Network folder in Windows Explorer, it shows me other devices connected to LAN... How does the Windows determine it?

Comment: Short of a port scan (which corporate networks may recognize as a threat) there's no definitive way to tell what's there and what's not.  Tools like nmap can do this sort of thing.  Is there any reason it has to be in Java?

Comment: If you are assuming a private network, as it seems you are, you can do this be subtracting the list of all possible private addresses from the list of addresses in use. This question then becomes how to list all the addresses in use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the list of IP addresses in a LAN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672153/how-to-get-the-list-of-ip-addresses-in-a-lan)

Comment: @PerwinCZ windows uses SMB usually for finding other systems.  That also can be blocked or not used like pings. ARP cannot be blocked however (or IP wont work) so it will always work for finding systems on the same LAN

Answer (score 0):

You can use ARP, its not directly supported in java though due to security reasons but there are bindings with jpcap, ie (https://github.com/mgodave/Jpcap/blob/master/sample/ARP.java).  ICMP(ping) would be an appropriate solution also but some firewalls on systems block it (http://www.inprose.com/en/content/icmp-ping-in-java).